# A couple of links to our products and 10 pages of crack/keygen/torrent/etc

Tags: google-search

If you try searching for our company and product name you'll get two useful links and 10 pages of hacker sites where eventually you can download the cracked version of our products.

How can we clean hacker links and leave only useful links to our prouct pages? We already checked the Google URL Removal Tool but within the 'Removal Type' options we can specify there is nothing meaningful to specify in this case.

Shall we proceed the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

File a [DMCA notice](http://www.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=ts.cs&ts=1114905) about those pages. Google will then remove them from their index.

Comment: Done! Do you know how much it takes to complete?

Comment: @devdept When I did it once it took a few days for them to do it. I would think your experience would be similar.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not like that, one week is passed and nothing happens.

Comment: They answered after one month but they answered...